# Error while setting up SonarCloud for a multimodule Maven project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarcloud

Project is hosted on:

- GitHub - opencellsoft/core
- Sonar project https://sonarcloud.io/project/configuration?id=opencellsoft_core
  Both github actions and local maven where tested

the used command locally : `mvn verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar`
secret was added to github or to env variables, and properties where added to core/pom.xml
Different solutions where tested:

- First Test
  As suggested by the Sonarcloud configuration page the below properties where added but we got an error

  <sonar.projectKey>opencellsoft_core</sonar.projectKey>
  <sonar.organization>opencellsoft</sonar.organization>
  <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>

***Error:***

```
Project 'opencellsoft_core' can't have 2 modules with the following key: opencellsoft_core
```

- Second attempt
  transform the projectkey to

  <sonar.projectKey>opencellsoft_core-${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectKey>

***Error:***

```
You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
```

- 3rd Attempt
  Add modulekey properties

<sonar.projectKey>opencellsoft_core</sonar.projectKey>
<sonar.moduleKey>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</sonar.moduleKey>

***Error:***

```
You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: resolved in this issue https://community.sonarsource.com/t/error-while-setting-up-sonarcloud-for-a-multimodule-maven-project/39880/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third solution was correct but need to add the secret token in Repository secrets instead of environment secrets in Github. More information can be found here  https://community.sonarsource.com/t/error-while-setting-up-sonarcloud-for-a-multimodule-maven-project/39880/2